# Ad hoc networking of Ubuntu 10.04 and Android 1.5

Tags: android, ubuntu-10.04, adhoc

I want to connect an android device to a host machine running ubuntu.
the ad-hoc connection made by Network Manager is not discovered by the android device. 
I have Gufw and allowed both packet directions.

Is the problem with the android version? 
a special config on android necessary? 
any hints?

thanx

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Ad hoc mode is not supported natively on android.
See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5102833/1071861