# Android Wireless Adaptor Support in Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, adapter, android-wireless

I need to re configure wireless adaptor to setup an adhoc network over android phones. I need a way to test it on emulator but i have heard it doesnt has support to it hence cannot be accessed. Is there any way i can do it ? The reconfiguring is done at runtime by a library file by executing low level commands.

In simpler words i need a way to connect 2 or more android virtual devices using wifi adhoc

Comment: My guess is that this isn't current possibly with non-rooted devices - see [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932150/can-android-do-peer-to-peer-ad-hoc-networking) [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100928/how-to-connect-android-wifi-to-adhoc-wifi) posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The emulator does not emulate any form of WiFi. It emulates a generic Internet connection.

Moreover, as Marvin points out, AFAIK, you cannot do ad-hoc mode with Android except on rooted hardware. Hence, most likely, you will need to purchase two devices that you can root.