# Creating an android WLAN multiplayer game

Tags: android, wifi, android-wireless

I'm fairly new to android development and want to develop a multiplayer game. I want multiple players to connect together over WLAN and join game rooms. It's meant to be played in a room so the phone can set up the server. Are there any tutorials out there? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As you'll see from [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5100928/1101070) questions, wifi ad-hoc mode is not possible on **non-rooted** devices. What this means is that you will need a *real* server to broker the connections (i.e. game rooms, moves, etc) between your players.