# How to restrict my mobile apps while my device in certain range in Wi-FI. i want to make application like sonic wall or firewall in Android?

Tags: android, wifi, restriction, firewall-access

I want to give restrict the usage of apps whenever device is in range of my wifi network. and at time my application will start automatically and it should always running within my wifi range, no one can able to disable or close/kill the app only app admin can do this. App will check the wireless networks available in range, and connect to network as soon as it is in range. person will not be able to switch off the wifi or connect to any other network. When device is in range of my wifi, apps will be restricted and only allowed app can be used. suppose we can restrict camera use in my wifi range and camera usage will become unrestricted when device is out of my wifi range. When device is out of my wifi range, person can use their device without any restriction. it is same like sonicwall or firewall can do in internet explorer in windows. we can only use some allowed pages in internet while sonicwall or firewall is on.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is not possible in Android. Apps have very limited permissions and they cannot restrict the behaviour of other apps AT ALL! [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100928/how-to-connect-android-wifi-to-adhoc-wifi) you will get some idea of how to connect to Wifi SSID. But what u ask for is like a device administrator and it is NOT possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not true! It is posable to restrict apps to WIFI only just install the free app Onovo https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.onavo.android.onavoid