# Bluetooth like behavior using wifi in android

Tags: java, android, android-wifi

Is it possible to mimic bluetooth like behaviour in android using Wifi adapter.I am trying to use Wifi to setup client sever application.I have created a system service in android 2.3.7. I want this service to identify the server automatically.As in bluetooth, A naive approach shall be to search for available devices and then send a connection request at specific port say 8080 and the connection is established. can this be done using wifi. In a nut shell i wish that the system services on two different devices communicate with each other using wifi,i.e., One device works as a ad-hoc wifi server and the other connects to it as a client Does this sounds doable? The basic point being to emulate the bluetooth like behavior in absence of bluetooth on emulator. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not an android expert, but I remember it not supporting ad-hoc connections, which seems to be what you'd like to do.

Related answer: [How to connect android wifi to adhoc wifi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100928/how-to-connect-android-wifi-to-adhoc-wifi)

Comment: i went through this. The post says " if there's a way to connect my android to an ad hoc network set-up from my laptop." I am asking is there a way to create an adhoc wifi using my android_device_1 and let android_device_2 connect to the adhoc connection created by android_device_1 ?

Comment: Would WiFi direct satisfy your problem ?  It's part of android 4.0.  Otherwise, android doesn't support ad-hoc.

Comment: i did look into wifi direct. and yest its true that its only available for android >4.0. i am looking for something to mimic it on android 2.3.7. I need to test my project for over avds and they all need to share data with each other. This is all what i want to do.